# How does C++ find the size of an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

**Difference From Other Questions**

I am not asking how to find the size, but how the computer finds the size.

**Goal**

I want to find out how C++ finds the size of an array (using `sizeof(array)`), and a 2D array (using `sizeof(array)`).

When I ran the code, I thought the output would be `3` and `6`. But it was `12` and `24`!? How do I make the the output `3` and `6`?

I don't know how to calculate the size of an array, so when I say "an output of three/six", I mean the amount of numbers in the array.

**Code**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int oneDArray [3] = {1, 2, 3};
    int twoDArray [2][3] = {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}};

    cout << sizeof(oneDArray) << "\n" << sizeof(twoDArray);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Value given by `sizeof` is measured in **bytes**.

Comment: You can use `std::size` to find the number of items in a raw array. However, for the 2D array that's the number of 1D arrays it consists of. Given an array *type* (which you can obtain e.g. via `decltype`) you can use `std::extent` to get more detailed information, or `std::rank` to find only the number items in the outermost array.

Comment: Do I format it like this: `std::rank << array;`? Because it says I have a missing template argument.

Comment: @SAcoder: No. http://cppreference.com provides reliable documentation of both the core language and the standard library.

Comment: [Look into `std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array). It wraps arrays with a number of helper utilities that are... Uhm... Helpful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[The `sizeof` operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof) returns the size in bytes, not elements.

For single dimensional arrays (*not* passed as a function argument, which would cause decay to a pointer), you can get the element count by dividing the size of the array by the size of the first element, e.g.

```
sizeof(oneDArray) / sizeof(oneDArray[0])  // Gets 3
```

For multidimensional arrays, that would tell you the size of the first dimension, not the number of elements total, so you'd need to drill down deeper:

```
sizeof(twoDArray) / sizeof(twoDArray[0])  // Gets 2 (first dimension of array)
sizeof(twoDArray) / sizeof(twoDArray[0][0])  // Gets 6 (number of elements)
```

You can of course explicitly name the type of an element to avoid nested indexing (`sizeof(twoDArray) / sizeof(int)` get 6 just fine), but I avoid it as a rule; it's too common for an array to change types during development (say, it turns out you need to use `int64_t` because you have values into the trillions), and if the whole expression isn't in terms of the array, it's easy to overlook it and end up with broken code.

Comment: Does `array.size()` find the size in bytes or the number of items in a dynamic array?

Comment: `array.size()` would give you the number of elements if `array` is a std::vector().

Comment: `.size()` on all `std::` containers return the number of elements

Comment: To be clear, in the C++ standard, there is nothing referred to as an "array" that has dynamic size. There are C-style arrays (the type you used in your question), which in strictly compliant C++ has a compile time determined size (though many compilers allow C99-style variable length arrays as a feature), and there is `std::array` which is templated on size, so the size is known at compile-time. `std::array` has a `.size()` method that reports the size in elements, C-style arrays don't have methods at all, and decay to pointers readily, so you usually need to pass their size around with them.

Answer (score 6):

`sizeof` returns bytes, if you expect number of elements, divide by the size of each element

```
cout << sizeof(oneDArray)/sizeof(int) << "\n" << sizeof(twoDArray)/sizeof(int);
```

[Output](http://cpp.sh/7qqoe):

```
3
6
```